# I am not able to check the username and password in my database. can anyone help me in this

Tags: php, html

Here i have login.html then action is logincheck.php and i need to check whether the user is authenticated or not. 
Here logincheck.php is

```
  <?php  
$uname = $_POST['username'];                                                                                        
$pword = $_POST['password'];



    $serverName = "<ip address , portnumber>";                                                                                  
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"testing", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"abc@123");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

        if( $conn )  
        {   
            $sqlquery="select * from emp where username='$username' and password='$password'";
            $query = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sqlquery);




            $row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query);
            $count=sqlsrv_num_rows($query);     


            if ($count === false )
                {

                    header('Location:/');                                                                               


                }
            else
                {   
                     header('Location: /main.html');                                                                    
                }  
            sqlsrv_close($con);                                                                                         

        }else{
            echo"<h1 >Database Connection Error...</h1>";                                                                   
        }      ?>
```

Database connection was established but whenever i execute this is automatically redirecting to "**header('Location:/');**"

I think i have problem with

```
   $sqlquery="select * from emp where username='$username' and password='$password'";
            $query = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sqlquery);

            $row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query);
            $count=sqlsrv_num_rows($query);
```

This lines.

Thank you

Comment: You're using `$username and $password` in your SQL string when it should be `$uname and $pword`

Comment: Never ever pass data you receive from a untrusted source without escapting into a sql query.

Comment: Yes, I change that still i didn't get result.

Comment: Use `var_dump($query);` and `var_dump($_POST);` and what do you get back?

Comment: I got answer. when i replace       $count=sqlsrv_num_rows($query);    with           $count=sqlsrv_has_rows($query);

Answer (score 1):

You're creating variables with the names `$uname` and `$pword` and refer to `$username` and `$password` this will not work of course, change them to the same name.

Comment: I changed as you said    $sqlquery="select * from emp where username='$uname' and password='$pword'";

Comment: Still same result.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed

```
        $row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query);
        $count=sqlsrv_num_rows($query);
```

with

```
        $count=sqlsrv_has_rows($query);
```

then i got result.